# Why does jenkins build from multiple commits when it shouldn't?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, git-commit, git-checkout

I have a parameterized job in jenkins. What it does it receives a git hash and then runs a checkout by commit hash (commit hash in the branches parameter). The problem is when jenkins will be offline for some time and in the meantime new commits will be pushed to the repo. When Jenkins is online again, receives a commit hash and when it is supposed to build this one commit, it takes all the commits that were'nt built in the meantime despite that only one hash was passed into checkout.

Why does that happen and how can that be avoided?

EDIT: Here's the job log:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tester
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage (CHECKOUT)
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
Entering stage CHECKOUT
Proceeding
[Pipeline] checkout
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url http://testrepo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://testrepo.git
> git --version # timeout=10
> git fetch --tags --progress http://testrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse <mycommithash>^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision <mycommithash> (detached)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f <mycommithash>
> git rev-list <someotherhash> # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: are you sure that it is only built as a parameterized build and no other triggers?  Is it possible that for each commit it is being triggered?  It would be helpful to have more information about the build job.

Comment: it is triggered, but if for example jenkins is offline then it pickups all unbuild commits

Comment: what does the build job history say for the reason it built an undesired commit?

Comment: it pickups the commits from the failed jobs. Eventually if I could stop jenkins from doing that, it would work (at least to some degree). Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check that it doesn't trigger for failed jobs?  There is a way to trigger parameterized builds or child builds only if parent was successful.  I don;t understand how your job is building if nothing else is triggering it.  Can you provide some of your config or screenshots.

Comment: it works from local git folder which has a post commit hook that sends hash of that commit to jenkins. Jenkins doesnt have any "hook" receivers or pollers, it is triggered by "buildwithparameters" http call that sends just the commit hash

Comment: Is the post commit hook sending just one (the latest) or are you getting all those queued up post commit hook triggers?  It sounds like the latter.  In which case jenkins is working correctly.

Comment: theres just one hash being sent